# Is there a function to convert an octal number to decimal?

Tags: python, numbers

I have a list of octal numbers that I want to convert into decimal; I used `"%d"` but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you mean "I have a list of strings that _look_ like octal numbers"? Because internally, there's no distinction between "octal" and "decimal" integers.

Comment: `int(str(your_num), 8)`

Comment: Do you mean *"strings that represent octal numbers"*? `int(n, 8)` will convert them to integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, this answer proposes a small modification on @ForceBru's answer, it appears that the numbers are formatted as floating points. Since your number is [`1.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880157/is-there-a-function-to-convert-an-octal-number-to-decimal#comment46022393_28880193). If the numbers are in reality integers, you can do this by performing a conversion first:

```
>>> your_num = 1.0
>>> int(str(int(your_num)),8)
1
```

If `your_num` is a string, you can first convert it to a `float` and then to an `int`:

```
>>> your_num = "1.0"
>>> int(str(int(float(your_num))),8)
1
```

(since it is possible you parsed the number as a `float`. Note that you will drop the decimal part the value in such case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `int(str(number), base=8)`.

Example output:

```
>>> int('024', 8)
20
```

If you want to use *integers*, you can do like this.

```
int(str(int(number)), 8)
```

Comment: I havetried  int(str(your_num), 8) but, it generates this error :ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 8: '1.0'

Comment: @user3801697: are we talking about integers or floats?

Comment: Then why does it print `1.0` (with **`.0`**)?

Comment: @user3801697, as you know, 1.0 _is not_ an integer.